# How to choose files that will go in deploy?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, deployment

I have this structure:

```
- Content
    - Scripts
    - Styles
- Static
    - default.css
    - default.js
```

The folder `Content` must be in the source control, because that is where we change the scripts and styles of the website. So I can `include` it in the project.

The files in the folder `Static` must not be in the source control, it is generated and makes no sense to enable `checkout` and `checkin`.

#### The problem

If I include the folder `Content` in the project it will take it when I publish the website. If I exclude it from project it will not work with the Source Control.

If I exclude `default.css` and `default.js` from the project it will not be in the source control, but it will not go in the publish (I do not wish to publish all files in project folder).

#### Question

Is there a way I can choose which files I want to ignore and which I want to include in the publish?

Comment: My "publish process" consists of one VS-integrated publish to a local folder and a second, CS-Script-based (i.e. some external batch file) publish process that takes data from the local folder being published to, as well as from several other locations. Maybe you can use such a way, too, to include your additional files?

Comment: Does this help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360579/post-publish-events. After a successful publish, have an automated script remove the content folder

Comment: @david yes, that answers my question as a "The only way is to create a program to modify the published website" and gives me a hint of the best way to achieve the expected behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(posting answer from comment...fwiw)...

[This question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360579/post-publish-events) details how to run a script or command after a successful publish in Visual Studio. You could create a script that deletes the `Content` folder after each publish...Or copies the rest of the site somewhere, leaving the `Content` folder behind and this would achieve what you are after.