# How to run .bat file on server after web deploy publish

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, publishing, webdeploy

I am using Web Deploy for publishing an ASP.NET MVCwebsite in Visual Studio 2010.
Is there any way to run a .bat file on server after this publish automatically?

Answer (score 2):

See: [Post Publish Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360579/post-publish-events)

You could create a [Windows Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) that runs on your IIS box and uses the [`FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) to monitor changes to your web root path and when it detects a file change run a [batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519328/executing-batch-file-in-c-sharp).