# Run application after database is deploy

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, database-project

I have a database project in Visual Studio 2013. After deployment of database objects is triggered several SQL scripts that insert, or update records in the tables.

After a total deployment, including post-deployment scripts I needed to run a custom console application that sends e-mails according to the list server administrators with information about successful or unsuccessful deployment.

Is it possible to do it in a database project?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15605489/is-there-any-way-to-call-custom-code-when-publishing

Comment: And there's always the option to wrap it in PowerShell or a batch file, check to see if it deployed successfully, and run the appropriate commands. I think we had a plug-in to our deployment tool that parsed the content for success/failure and knew which was which so it could take the appropriate action as well.